# Heroku routing: May I route to an inner directory?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, routes, gulp

I have a single page application based on this Bootstrap template [here](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/resume/). It is basically a Gulp application with my online CV. It is hosted at Heroku and if I manage to solve this current problem I'll point my personal domain to it.

But the point now is that I am not an advanced Heroku user and I am surely missing something.

The problem is:

- At my application root directory I created another directory named `apps`, and inside it another directory `blog`. Now I have this:

  `my_app_root_dir -> apps -> blog -> index.html`
- This index.html file contains a really small React application written by scratch, i.e., I haven't used `create-react-app` and just wrote everything directly and included React like this:

  `<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.js"></script>`
  `<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.js"></script>`
- Now I would like to have a link for this blog application in my homepage, something like:

  `<a href="apps/blog/index.html">Blog</a>`
- It works very fine when I run it in my own environment. I click the link and the blog page loads correctly.
- But when I deploy it to Heroku and click the Blog link, it just loads the Homepage but it messes up with the CSS. When I use `heroku logs` to see what is happening, it is clear that it is routing my request to the initial page. Which is only natural, after all it is a single page appliction!

My question is:

**Is there some way I may use to instruct Heroku to redirect me to this inner directory?**

**In other words, how may I tell Heroku to redirect all requests with the form `http://myapp.herokuapp.com/apps/blog/` to `apps/blog/index.html`?**

or yet another way:

**May I leave this single page application scheme and 'embeed' other other sub-applications this way I am trying to do?**

This is probably a stupid question for those who know Heroku well, but I've researched for a while and found no answer to my problem. If this is not possible I'll have to find another solution to host my website. Maybe a VPS where I may reproduce the same configuration I have in my development machine, which works perfectly well, as I previously mentioned.

UPDATE:

**package.json**

```
{
    "title": "eddealmeidda",
    "name": "startbootstrap-resume",
    "version": "4.1.1",
    "description": "Ed de Almeida's base website",
    "keywords": [
        "Ed de Almeida",
        "website",
        "site"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://eddealmeida.herokuapp.com/",
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/IntelligenceAndTechnology/ed-de-almeida/issues",
        "email": "edvaldoajunior@gmail.com"
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "author": {
        "name": "Ed de Almeida",
        "email": "edvaldoajunior@gmail.com"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "8.9.1"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/IntelligenceAndTechnology/ed-de-almeida.git"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "devicons": "^1.8.0",
        "jquery": "3.3.1",
        "serve": "^8.2.0",
        "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "browser-sync": "^2.24.5",
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "gulp-clean-css": "3.9.4",
        "gulp-header": "2.0.5",
        "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
        "gulp-sass": "4.0.1",
        "gulp-uglify": "3.0.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "serve -s -p $PORT ."
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with your `package.json`?

Comment: Updated, @antzshrek.

Comment: Noted! But how do you start your server locally? Your logic of `"scripts": {"start": "serve -s -p $PORT ."}` looks weird.

Comment: It works fine at Heroku, even looking weird! LOL Locally I start if with ir or then `gulp dev`.

Comment: To use my weird logic locally I do `PORT=5000 npm start` and it runs perfectly well. Ar Heroku this bind automatically with the $PORT Heroku decides to provide the app with.

Comment: I checked the the site you were talking about, http://*******eida.herokuapp.com/apps/blog and inspected it, I noticed your CSS files aren't seen.

Comment: So? Do you believe this is the problem? CSS files are under /apps, because they are going to be shared among other apps in the future. But this is not the cause of the routing error.